# Nginx can access static folder but not other folders inside it. Throws sub-folder/index.html is not found

Tags: django, nginx, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy my django app on google cloud platform. I am using nginx and gunicorn. I am following [this guide](https://medium.com/@_christopher/deploying-my-django-app-to-a-real-server-part-ii-f0c277c338f4).

I have created a file - `le_website` - under the folder sites-available. This is the code -

```
server {

   listen 80;
   server_name 10.xxx.x.x;
   location = /favicon.ico {access_log off;log_not_found off;} 

   location = /static/ {
     root /home/jainpriyanshu1991/learnEarn/le-webiste;    
   }


   location = / {
     include proxy_params;
     proxy_pass http://unix:/home/jainpriyanshu1991/learnEarn/le-webiste/le_website.sock;
   }
 }
```

When I try the url `myIPaddress/static/` , it works and shows the folders inside it. But it does not work for any subfolder within static. It gives `/usr/share/nginx/html/static/img/index.html` is not found for img folder inside static. Similarly, when I try the url `myIPaddress/` it opens the homepage of website but again, it does not work for any other link and gives error. For about page it gives error `/usr/share/nginx/html/about` failed (2: No such file or directory).

Comment: Do you mean to use the `=` modifier in the last two `location` blocks? Try: `location /static/ { ... } location / { ... }`

Comment: @RichardSmith could you add your comment as an answer in order to give visibility to other members of the community? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the tutorial you were following. `location = ...` exactly matches a single URI, whereas you need to match all URIs below `/static/`.

Use:

```
location = /favicon.ico { ... } 
location /static/ { ... }
location / { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.